# How to convert a contacts list to an opted-in email marketing list?

Tags: bulk-email

I've got a customer who's got a couple of thousand contacts in their CRM but they're not opted-in, they're just the people they deal with day to day. We want to start doing some email marketing.

**What's the right and best way to approach these contacts to try and get them to opt in?**

By "right" I mean from a legal/compliance/GDPR point of view. Presumably just adding them to the list and waiting for them to opt out is a no-no, if not illegal?

By "best" I'm wondering if there are established ways of approaching the contact, we can't be the first to find ourselves in this situation. Things that spring to mind are a one-time bulk email to all saying "we've got a new mailing list, sign up here..." but that seems like it would have a pretty low uptake.

Comment: Send them each an email saying "if you don't click here to remain on our list, you are going to be removed".  The term "opt-in" should give you a clue ;o)

Comment: Yea, thanks @Steve, I'm wondering if, as an industry, we have some known good or poor ways to approach this.

Comment: Good way?  Do as I suggested.  Poor way? Just about anything else as you won't have their permission.